# Task getting canceled when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

I am using the c# TaskScheduler to start some tasks and it is throwing a TaskCanceledException somehow. I stepped all the way through the function the task calls and it completes fine and no exceptions are thrown at all. I am using IEnumerable and yield for part of the stuff in the master task function, not sure if that causes issues with tasks, wouldn't think it would. I am so lost right now, I don't see anything wrong with my code and nothing is failing I can see in the task thread.

I simplified my code to the below but this is the structure.

```
Action[] Jobs = new Action[] { Job1(), Job2(), etc };
Task[] Tasks = new Task[Jobs.Length];

try
{
    int I = 0;

    foreach (Action Act in Jobs)
    {
        Tasks[I] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Act());
        I++;
    }
    Task.WaitAll(Tasks, 300000);
}
catch (AggregateException AgEx) { throw AgEx.Flatten(); }
```

I also tried this and it works fine

```
Thread NewJob = new Thread(() => DoJob());
NewJob.IsBackground = true;
NewJob.Start();
NewJob.Join(300000);
```

Comment: a `for` loop seems better than a `foreach` in this. Also, `I` and `Act`? Uppercase variables are horrendous. Use `i` and `act`.

Comment: Can you provide a complete piece of code that shows the problem?  What are the exact types of Job1 and Job2?

Comment: For debugging, get rid of the try/catch. In the debugger with break on throw, where does it throw?  What's the stack?  You're leaving out too much info/context AFAICT

Comment: If you just execute the actions in the loop instead of starting tasks, how does it behave?

Comment: Yea I probably should use a for loop. I don't really want to post all the code because it is private. I will try removing all the try catches. I will try it without task and see what happens tomorrow. I don't think uppercase variables are that bad, they are for single letters like I did. It all depends what you are use too. I happen to hate them, it's all preference.

Comment: Ok I did a test to just use a regular thread and it completed just fine like I said.

Comment: I fixed this issue for now using AutoResetEvent, Regular Thread class and WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles). But I still would like to know why using Tasks framework doesn't work